# Training multiclass NN in Keras using binary cross-entropy gives higher score than using categorical cross-entropy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, deep-learning

By mistake, I used the binary cross-entropy loss function instead of categorical cross-entropy when training my NN for predicting Named Entities in text. I have a multiclass problem with 3 classes, which is heavily imbalanced. The model is developed using Keras.

I evaluated my model using the evaluation script for CoNLL-2002 (not Keras build-in evaluation methods). However, I achieve higher scores using binary cross-entropy than using categorical cross-entropy and can't understand why? Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Thanks!

Comment: You are comparing two completely different losses, any comparison makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, that is true and I should use categorical cross-entropy since I have a multiclass problem. However, when I mistakenly used binary cross-entropy I found out that by using this loss function, the model achieved higher precision, recall, and F1 score (based on the CoNLL-2002 evaluation script). I am not trying to compare them, just understand if there is any possible explanation why binary cross-entropy seems superior?